# Is there an open source live support application using PHP, Jabber and Google Talk

Tags: xmpp, google-apps, google-talk

I have 2-5 support reps who use Google Apps including Google Talk

I want to provide a "Live Support" option on my web site.

When one or more employees log in to Google Apps the live support option should become available.

Ideally the live support feature should simply enable a 1:1 chat session with a support rep with the ability to add additional support reps.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers a way to put Chat badges in your website so it's possible to chat with ONE user, but i've never heard of such thing. At least not open source.

You can see similar functionality in [www.olark.com](http://www.olark.com) and [www.zopim.com](http://www.zopim.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is no open source project, but there is this tutorial to make notification app and chat.

**http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-realtimeXMPPtut/section5.html**